# bash wait for sh file to complete

Tags: bash

I'm running a bash file which contains another sh file call and curl cmd, the inner sh file will run for a unpredictable time and the curl must run after inner bash is finished. Now i'm using `sleep` to wait the inner to finish. is there any better way to do this?

```
 ./inner.sh
 sleep 30
 curl  GET 'http://localhost:9092/OTHER/core/other/htmlreport'
```

Comment: The sleep is not needed. Bash _will_ wait for the other file to complete before it executes the next line.

Comment: i tried without the sleep, still curl will immediately

Comment: Whats in `inner.sh`? Does it start any background jobs?

Comment: yes, inner have more than 100 curls

Comment: @boycod3 Try `pwait -P "$BASHPID"` before curl.

Comment: what is "$BASHPID"

Comment: @boycod3, try `LESS='+/\ *BASHPID' man bash`

Comment: The proper fix is probably to modify `inner.sh` so that _it_ waits for all of its subprocesses to finish. Perhaps make this optional behavior if you don't want it to be the default.

Comment: @tripleee fix it with wait in inner.sh ?

Comment: That's how you wait for subprocesses, yes.

Comment: just simply put wait at the very end of inner.sh ?

Comment: @boycod3 Better show your inner.sh script.

Comment: @konsolebox inner.sh file have 100 curl api calls.

Comment: @boycod3 We don't like guessing. We can't help you if you don't provide accurate debugging information.

Comment: @konsolebox the info i gave is not a guess, inner.sh file have 100s of curl cmd which include POST,GET,DELETE,PUT methods.

Comment: @boycod3 If there's nothing but curl commands, adding a `wait` in the end should suffice.

Comment: @boycod3 Normally, a script will automatically wait for each command (e.g. each `curl`) before going on to the next one. `inner.sh` is clearly doing *something* nonstandard to avoid waiting for the various `curl` commands, but we don't know what because we haven't seen the script. Depending on exactly how it was done, `wait` might or might not make the script wait for them to finish. For example, if they were backgrounded (with `&`) *from a subshell*, `wait` won't wait for them.